# .NET Callback function surrounded by a javascript Promise only works the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery

We are doing call backs inside Sharepoint 2010 to simulate web service behaviour. Now I have embedded this standard library with a promise. The problem is it only works the first time. All subsequent calls fail to resolve the newly created promise. With debugging it showed all subsequent calls use the deferred of the first call (deferred.state() was 'resolved'). So we came up with the following code (the deferred object is fetched via 'getDeferredInstance', but still the first-deferred-call is used (we checked this by adding a property inside the Chrome dubgger to the first deferred instance). CODE:

```
  self.doCall = function () {
      self.deferred = $.Deferred();
      self.getDeferredInstance = function() {return self.deferred;}

      self.onSuccess = function(result) {
          var instance = self.getDeferredInstance();
          instance.resolve(result);
      }

      self.onError = function() {
          var instance = self.getDeferredInstance();
          instance.reject();
      }

      apicontrol.doRequest("Api." + self.serviceName + "." + self.operationName, JSON.stringify(self.data), self.onSuccess, self.onError);

      return self.deferred.promise();
  }
```

Comment: Uh, don't store the deferred on `self` (where it will collide with the other calls), but simply refer to it through closure?

Comment: Yeah the reason was I was playing around with the code to make it work. This was my last version and with using self. My first version was without storing it using self, but this did not work either.

Comment: Can you post that as well, please?

Comment: I forgot to answer this remark. The solution was to store every call to this function inside an array supplied with a unique key. So a setDeferred(key, deferred) at the beginning of doCall and the onSuccess and onError do a getDeferred(key).